# Configure Entity Framework to pick connection strings from Azure CloudConfiguration File?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, web-config

We are using EF-6 in our web roles & worker roles. These roles are encapsulated into a single cloud service project.

In order to manage config settings in a better way, we have moved most of our config keys into cloud project & we read them using [CloudConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.aspx).

> But for packages like Entity Framework or Enterprise Library we can't
>   tell AppDomain to read settings from Cloud Config file. EF looks into
>   respective App.Config or Web.Config of the project.

Is there any way to tell EF to read connection strings from cloud config file?

Comment: EF will use the connection string that it built the model with, but you can customize this by overriding the generated behavior. I think if you provided some code as to what you have or what you would like to do it would be easier to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the T4 template file Model.Context.tt to use

```
base(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("YourEntities"))
```

When you regen your model the resulting Model.Context.cs file will use the CloudConfigurationManager.

Comment: How do I specify `providerName` in this case?

Comment: Similar questions that might help [Is this how to set Context Connection String Using CloudConfigurationManager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199958/is-this-how-to-set-context-connection-string-using-cloudconfigurationmanager) and [Entity Framework DbContext in Azure Web Role](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679088/entity-framework-dbcontext-in-azure-web-role)

Comment: In my case it was the Model.Context.Context.tt file, and I also had to add the azure using:   `using Microsoft.Azure;`