# Customize DbContext using connection string from ServiceConfiguration (Azure)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I am using the entity-framework with Code First approach and I have a custom DbContext.
My connectionstring is defined in the ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg and ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg files.

```
 public CustomContext()
                : base("dbActivity")
 {
    ...
```

When the above code executes, it tries to check my web.config and not the ServiceConfiguration file from an azure solution.

UPDATE:
Here is my connectionString in the ServiceConfiguration file:

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
  <Setting name="dbActivity" value="Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=ra;User ID=user;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

Exception:

> No connection string named 'Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=ra;User ID=user;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;' could be found in the application config file."

Is it possible to make it check the ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configure Entity Framework to pick connection strings from Azure CloudConfiguration File?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222862/configure-entity-framework-to-pick-connection-strings-from-azure-cloudconfigurat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. It's necessary to use the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class.

```
public RAActivityContext()
    : base((new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("dbRAActivity")).ToString()))
{            

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an overloaded constructor that takes an actual connection string.

This should do the trick:

```
public CustomContext()
                : base(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("dbActivity"))
{
    // stuff here
}
```

Of course, the setting contains the (full) connection string.

Comment: I tried this solution before, but I still get the same exception. It looks like it is only accepting the connection string name, not the connection string itself

Comment: What is the exception that is thrown?  What version of EF are you using?  What does the configuration in your `ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg` look like?  I am doing the above and it is working fine with EF 6.

Comment: WebRole or WorkerRole? Version of EF?

Comment: I am using EF6 and WorkerRole

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it you can directly load it from a different config but there is a constructor for dbcontext that takes a connection string as input.

```
string connectionString = LoadFromConfig();
var context = new CustomContext(connectionString );
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this, but wasn't able to change the actual DbContext constructor as it was in a shared library that was also used by projects that used an app.config. I ended out coming up with an alternative solution which was to programatically modify the app.config connection string inside the worker role itself.

See this for a way to do that: [Change connection string & reload app.config at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502411/change-connection-string-reload-app-config-at-run-time)

The code I used was

```
string databaseConnectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("dbActivity");
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ConnectionStringsSection connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection) config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["dbActivity"].ConnectionString = databaseConnectionString;
config.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

For this to work you need to have an empty connection string inside the app.config for which it will overwrite

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbActivity" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```